# Android multiple launcher Activities?

Tags: android

I have 2 activities one with the following filter

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Another with

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This creates 2 icons when installing the app. if no activity in the app is running when I click each icon it opens the proper screen, but when I already have a screen opened in the background when I click the second icon it opens the app and doesn't go to the proper Activity (2nd activity).

I tried setting android:noHistory="true" on the activity, but still behaves the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [android:taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) maybe resolve your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:launchMode="singleTask"

```
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this work you can add attribute `android:taskAffinity`, By default all activities in manifest has the same task affinity which is default to the main package. But whichever activity you want to open from another task, for that you can define 'taskAffinity' in the activity tag using, 
android:taskAffinity="com.package.activity_package_name" you can read more about this
on this [activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) page